# An ivy function for recently opened files?

Tags: buffers, ivy, recentf

I know that setting `ivy-use-virtual-buffers` leads to recently opened files being shown in the `ivy-switch-buffer` completion. However, I don't want this.

What I want is a separate function for opening recent files. When I invoke `recentf-open-file`, I want the `ivy` completion for recent files, instead of the clunky recentf menu.

Doom Emacs provides a neat implementation of this, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in vanilla Emacs. Do I have to write my own function for this? This seems redundant considering the fact that `ivy` already has the mechanism to do this.

Comment: elisp tag doesn't apply here. Please read [Elisp tag info](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info)

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `counsel-recentf`, which comes with counsel.

Just `M-x counsel-recentf` or bind it to any keys you'd like and that's all you're looking for.

Loosely speaking `Ivy` is the completion backend, `counsel` provides functionality to use ivy "replacing" some popular commands with ivy-style completion.

Comment: Thanks, I've discovered `crux-recentf-find-file` and checked the source code. This function is easy to implement using `completing-read` and `recentf-list`.

Comment: Chances are that if you installed ivy also did it with basic counsel.